# Using ::after css not working below

Tags: css

There must be something that I am missing, but I am trying to use `::after` in my css, but unfortunately it isn't working.

My css code is below.

```css
.test {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #444;
}
.test::after {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  height: 240px;
  width: 240px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: It's not working is not s sufficient problem description.

Comment: after requires always `content:''` ... and something to give dimensions like display or absolute/fixed position

Comment: @PeeHaa you are correct, but i didn't know that it always requires `content: ''` and I'm sure others don't either, but you are correct, it is a bad question and is sure to be downvoted

Comment: @DaniP does it also always need to be set to `position: absolute`?

Comment: NO .. as I mention you need any property that gives the element box behavior like display.

Comment: @DaniP thanks! when i asked the question your comment wasn't there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need add `content: ''` to pseudo-class :after or :before and set the position to absolute.

```css
.test {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #444;
  position:relative;
}
.test:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  height: 240px;
  width: 240px;
  background: red;
  content: ''
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

but if you want you can use it without absolute, just add some float to it, because pseudo-classes generates like inside the parent node.

```css
.test {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #444;
  position:relative;
}
.test:after {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  float: right;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

But if you need use it like icon, inside the block better way use it with absolute.

Comment: thanks! does position always need to be set at absolute?